# Embedded Laravel App In Iframe, Give 302 Error On Login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, iframe, csrf-token

I'm trying to use the `Laravel app` in some other domain within `iframe`.

I had written a `FrameMiddleware` in which I have allowed that domain in the header

```
 public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->header('Content-Security-Policy', 'frame-ancestors http://localhost');
        return $response;
    }
```

and by using the above middleware cors origin error removed.

As my `Laravel app` needs authentication from the iframe. and it's using form submission, not API.  Then it starts to give a 
 `419 error`. I resolved by adding a login route in `VerifyCsrfToken` Middleware `$except` array for excluding `csrf` error.

then I check `network` and the `post` request for login give 302 error

[image: laravel within iframe give 302 error for post request]

I tested the authentication method and authenticated user object is returning with `Dashboard` page redirect and then `302 error code` shown.

Moreover, I had set `same_site => null` in `config/session.php` but still not working.

Comment: 302 is not an error, it's a redirect code

Comment: Try setting the same_site policy to None instead of null

Comment: @apokryfos I already tried it  but not work it gives the same code `302`

Comment: Try also setting the cookie to be `secure` and running your site under https. In chrome and Firefox (at least) the `SameSite=None` policy will not work over http

Comment: @apokryfos I have tested on `https` using `ngrok` but still not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [@apokryfos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487813/apokryfos) said, I need to set the `cookie` to be `secure` and set `SameSite=None`.

###### Goto : `config/session.php`

set:
`'same_site' => 'none'` and `'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', true)` **OR** by setting `SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE = true` in `.env` file.

and don't forget to create `FrameMiddleware` as you can [follow-my-question-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69374643/embedded-laravel-app-in-iframe-give-302-error-on-login) and `white_labeled` the domain i.e http://localhost in which you are embedding iframe.

**Note:** you can verify *`cookies are secured or not`* along with *`SameSite=Null`*  by using browser dev-tools as shown in the below image:

[image: cookies secured and SameSite=Null Verification]